# Contact RecordType cannot be set to Contact by API

Tags: c#, soap, salesforce

I have created a C# project, connect Salesforce Enterprise WSDL as WebReference and trying to create the Contact

```
var recordTypes = sforceService.query("select Id from RecordType where sObjectType = 'Contact'");

var contact = new Contact
    {
      LastName = textTemplate,
      RecordType = (RecordType)recordTypes.records[0],
      Email = textTemplate + "@test.com",
      Phone = "1234567890",
    };

    res = sforceService.create(new sObject[] { contact });
```

And get an error:
`"Field name provided, Id is not an External ID or indexed field for RecordType"`

How should I set RecordType in this case?

UPD. I should fill `string RecordTypeId` field instead of `RecordType RecordType` field

```
RecordTypeId = recordTypes.records[0].Id
```

Comment: Yup, you got it, it should be RecordTypeId and the value is the Id field of a RecordType instance. See the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps.htm) for a complete list of fields on a Contact object.

Answer (score 0):

```
ID  recordTpeId=Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('recordTypeName').getRecordTypeId();
```

Comment: There might be two reasons either there is no access or there is no record type.And Quering the record type requires a SOQL transaction But geeting secord type from Scema doesnot count as a SOLQ transaction

Comment: I've meant to explain it in your answer... You can edit it anytime!